# Logstash matches multiple value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

**1)** This is my **logstash.conf** file

```
input {
  beats {
    type => beats
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "\[(?<logtime>([0-9]|[\-\+\.\:\ ])*)\] \[(?<level>([a-z-A-Z])*)\] \[(?<msg>(.)+)\] (?<exception>(.)+)" }
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => [ "logtime", "level", "msg", "exception" ]
    remove_field => [ "beat", "offset", "source", "prospector", "host", "tags" ]
  }  
}

output {
  if [type] == "beats"{
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      manage_template => false
      index => "%{+YYYY.MM.dd}-container.api" 
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}" 
      user => "elastic"
      password => "secret"
    }
  }
}
```

**2)** I tested my grok with the debugger as you see below

[image]

**3)** This is what logstash writes to elasticsearch

```
  {
    "_index": "2019.01.28-container.api",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "pZctlWgBojxJzDZGWqZz",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "type": "beats",
      "level": "Debug",
      "@timestamp": "2019-01-28T15:56:41.295Z",
      "msg": [
        "Hosting starting",
        "exception"
      ],
      "@version": "1",
      "logtime": [
        "2019-01-28 15:23:12.911 +03:00",
        "level"
      ],
      "message": "[2019-01-28 15:23:12.911 +03:00] [Debug] [Hosting starting] exception 2",
      "exception": "exception 2",
      "input": {
        "type": "log"
      }
    }
  }
```

**4)** What I want to see is

```
  {
    "_index": "2019.01.28-container.api",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "pZctlWgBojxJzDZGWqZz",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "type": "beats",
      "level": "Debug",
      "@timestamp": "2019-01-28T15:56:41.295Z",
      "msg": "Hosting starting",
      "logtime": "2019-01-28 15:23:12.911 +03:00",
      "message": "2019-01-28 15:23:12.911 +03:00 Debug Hosting starting [exception 2]",
      "exception": "exception 2"
    }
  }
```

Comment: so, the only thing that are wrong is the msg and logtime right?

Comment: Yes. I expect them as a single string value but they have multiple values as array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with

```
mutate {
    add_field => [ "logtime", "level", "msg", "exception" ]
}
```

The fields you are adding are already created by the grok filter, doing it again is useless, it will only transform the already present field in an array and add to the array the new value, since the [mutate.addField](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) use a hash, it will add to the field `logtime` the value `level` and to the field `msg` the value `exception`.

Answer (score 2):

```
mutate {
    add_field => [ "logtime", "level", "msg", "exception" ]
}
```

This is the same as:

```
mutate {
        add_field => { 
              "logtime" => "level" 
              "msg" => "exception" 
        }
   }
```

That's why the array exists, and with multiple values. Since you define the variables names on the grok pattern, you don't have to specified again. So as baudsp says, you can remove this "add field".

Comment: Thanks for second code snippet. @baudsp just got the quick answer. So I can only upvoted yours.